# "On/at the 8th hour"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-request

If something happens, for example, between 7 PM and 8 PM, can I say it happened "on/at the 8th hour"? Is it allowed in English (or something to that effect)?

Comment: No, there is no expression like that. You can only say 'between seven and eight in the evening'.

Comment: Nobody says that, and if you did, you'd get puzzled looks.

Comment: *On/at the Xth hour* means when it's *exactly* that hour—not when it's halfway to or past it. On the other hand, you could say something like *the bottom of the 7th hour* to mean 7:30. It's not very common, but I've heard it used before. It might come from baseball terminology, but I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: You could say "during the 8th hour" in the context of something that lasts several hours. E.G. the charity telethon was not bringing in a lot of money until Paul McCartney made a surprise appearance during the 8th hour

Comment: @Kevin What does this mean: "Only one broadcast network — NBC — stayed live with the House proceedings during the 8 p.m. hour, [...]" (from here: https://www.nytimes.com/2019/12/19/business/media/fox-news-impeachment-ratings.html)? Between 7 and 8 or between 8 and 9? Is it okay to use it?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev - that article, introducing its theme, says "Roughly 11 million people tuned into the big-three cable news channels, Fox News, CNN and MSNBC, **from 8 to 9 p.m.**". I would only use "the 8 pm hour" about a TV show or other regular scheduled event that starts at 8 pm and lasts exactly one hour. It is US broadcasting jargon to talk about 'hours' - e.g. a variety hour, the Champion Spark Plug Hour (a radio show sponsored by that company).

Comment: Sergey, yes, it is ok to use it as @MichaelHarvey said.